# graphene mutation returns 400 - won't pass id field properly

Tags: django, reactjs, graphql, graphene-django

I have been using graphene in django with graphql and a React frontend.

I can get a create mutation to work, but an edit one won't - even tho the query without $ variables works in graphiQL

My gql const in React is:

```
export const EDIT_PERSON = gql`
  mutation personEdit($id: id, $input: PersonInputType!) {
    personEdit(id: id, input: $input) {
      person {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

id is set from a handler and the submit function in the form looks like:

```
<form
          autoComplete="off"
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            editPerson({
              variables: {
                id: id,
                input: {
                  firstName: firstName,
                  lastName: lastName,
                  address: address
                }
              }
            });
          }}
        >
```

My PersonEdit mutation in django looks like:

```
class PersonEdit(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = ID(required=True)
        input = PersonEditInputType(required=True)
    person = Field(PersonType)

    @classmethod
    def mutate(cls, root, info, **data):
        serializer = PersonSerializer(data=data.get('input'))
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        person = Person.objects.get(id=data.get('id'))
        print("PERSON", serializer.data)
        person.first_name = serializer.data['first_name']
        person.last_name = serializer.data['last_name']
        person.address = serializer.data['address']
        return PersonEdit(person=person.save())
```

Why will editing not work?

Comment: 400 means the query is either malformed or is otherwise failing validation. Check the actual response you're getting from the server in the Network tab of your browser's DevTools for details around what is wrong with the request.

Comment: Yes but why? It's because no $ in front of the 4th id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mutation should look like this

```
export const EDIT_PERSON = gql`
  mutation personEdit($id: ID!, $input: PersonInputType!) {
  personEdit(id: $id, input: $input) {
    person {
      id
    }
   }
 }
`;
```

Here it should be `id: $id` not `id: id`.